# Gradle's Java Project API does not provide access to preserve API in project.sync

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have written a Gradle plugin, written mostly in Java and some Groovy. I am trying to access the Project API, specifically the [Project.sync](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#sync-org.gradle.api.Action-) method. I was able to get most things working, but I am unable to figure out how to access the "preserve" method of the underlying Sync task.

I tried casting the object passed to the Action which I pass into Project.sync, but the object appears to be some sort of internal Gradle CopySpecWrapper object and it's not clear how to get access to the Sync task object which exposes the [preserve](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync:preserve(org.gradle.api.Action)) method.

Here is the relevant code fragment which shows how I tried to solve the problem:

```java
project.sync(new Action<CopySpec>() {
    public void execute(CopySpec copySpec) {
        copySpec.from(project.zipTree(myArchive));
        copySpec.into(expandDir);
        if (copySpec instanceof Sync) {
            Sync sync = (Sync) copySpec;
            sync.preserve(new Action<PatternFilterable>() {
                @Override
                public void execute(PatternFilterable patt) {
                    patt.include("**/*");
                    patt.exclude("myArchive/**/*");
                }
            });
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to resolve Sync task to preserve existing files.");
        }
    }
});
```

In my case the RuntimeException is hit.

Looking for the correct way to call Project.sync and be able to configure the pattern filter for the preserve functionality of the Sync task.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4553). It seems like they forgot the task type specific `preserve` method when they introduced the `project.sync` method.

Please note, that this bug is not the only reason why your code causes the `RuntimeException` to be thrown. Even without the bug, you would not be able to cast the passed `CopySpec` to the task type `Sync`. The method `project.sync` has nothing to do with the task type `Sync`, they just share the same interface for configuration.

Right now, there is no way to use `preserve` in combination with a `project.sync`. The two possible workarounds are:

1. Use a task of type `Sync`. Actually, this should be the preferred way anyhow, as actions like file deletion / copying should not happen during *configuration phase* anyhow (and it seems like you want your plugin to behave that way).
2. It should be possible to mimic the behavior of the `project.sync` method by calling `project.delete` and `project.copy` successively. You can pass a `FileCollection` to the `delete` method that excludes the files you want to preserve. For the `copy` method, you may need to set the `duplicatesStrategy` to `exclude` to prevent overwriting of the preserved files.

Comment: Thanks. My current workaround is essentially project.delete and project.copy. I did think about using a Sync task, but this code is deep inside the implementation of a custom task in my plugin and then I was dealing with the complexity of my task generating additional tasks in the containing project, and getting that right in terms of config phase vs execution phase. The code does not kick in during configuration phase but during the execution phase of my custom task. Thanks for the confirmation and pointer to the bug.

Comment: I was confused by the fact that project.sync in the doc shows preserve. Should have explicitly tested it in the Gradle DSL I guess :-) Bug link makes that clear.

Comment: The cast was because I was hoping the CopySpec impl passed to the Action would be an instance of Sync (given that Sync implements CopySpec interface), but it wasn't :-(